# owl-carousel slider not working responsively

Tags: responsive-design, owl-carousel

I have set up the owl-carousel slider and it works perfectly fine in jsbin
http://jsbin.com/zivahewise/2/edit?html,css,output

responsive and all that. However, when I implement it on Boostrap 3, the responsive feature isn't working. Anyone knows why?

Thanks!

Comment: Please refer This Stackoverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28070885/owl-carousel-not-working-maybe-i-linked-something-incorrectly/37088540#37088540

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you use bootstrap class container. You can remove 
for ex. 
`<div class='container'>` and use CSS manually . 
I think all will work fine. ;)

Example right code
HTML:

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
   <div> Your Content </div>
   <div> Your Content </div>
   <div> Your Content </div>
   <div> Your Content </div>
   <div> Your Content </div>
   <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    nav:true, 
    margin:10, 
    responsiveClass:true,            
    responsive:{
      0:{
         items:1 
      },
      480:{
         items:2, // from 480 to 677 
        nav:false 
      },

     678:{
        items:4, 
        center:true 
     },

     960:{
        items:5, 
        margin:20,
       center:false 
    },

    1200:{
       items:6,
       loop:false,
       margin: 30,
    }
  }
 })
```