# Owl carousel not working, maybe I linked something incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, owl-carousel

I an trying to use the owl carousel in my new project. I seem to be having an issue with it. So far only the HTML and CSS is working. I am somehow doing something wrong with the Script. Could someone possibly lend me a hand and take a look and point me in the right direction where I am messing up?

Here is a link to the website. The Owl Carousel is close to the bottom of the website. You will see two "partners" sections. The top is just the demo HTML, and the bottom is what I am trying to use to create the carouse. I am just using dummy images for the time being. [CloudPoint DIV Site](http://www.cloudpointtech.com/x123/)

Here is the website where I got the code from. [Owl Carousel Demo](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/images.html)

Here are some snippets of the code. If you need any further details I will do my best to provide them.

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
 
      autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
 
      items : 4,
      itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
      itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]
 
  });
</script>
```

```css
.grayscale {
  border: 0px solid black;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  /* For Webkit browsers */
  filter: gray;
  /* For IE 6 - 9 */
  -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
  /* Transition for Webkit browsers */
}

.grayscale:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  filter: none;
}


#owl-demo .owl-item{
  margin: 3px;
}
#owl-demo .owl-item img{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="owl-demo">


 <div class="owl-item grayscale" style="width: 293px;"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/technics/" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="owl-item grayscale" style="width: 293px;"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/technics/" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="owl-item grayscale" style="width: 293px;"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/technics/" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="owl-item grayscale" style="width: 293px;"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/technics/" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="owl-item grayscale" style="width: 293px;"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/technics/" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="owl-item grayscale" style="width: 293px;"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/technics/" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="owl-item grayscale" style="width: 293px;"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/technics/" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="owl-item grayscale" style="width: 293px;"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/technics/" alt="Owl Image"></div>

</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
 
      autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
 
      items : 4,
      itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
      itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]
 
  });
</script>
```

```html
<?php

// ******************* Sidebars ****************** //

if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {
 register_sidebar(array(
  'name' =>_('CloudPoint Right Sidebar'),
        'id' => 'right-sidebar',
        'description' =>_('widgets in this area will be shown on the right-hand side.'),
  'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
  'after_widget' => '</div><!--END WIDGET-->',
  'before_title' => '<h2 class="sidebar_title">',
  'after_title' => '</h2>',
 ));
}


// ******************* Add Custom search ****************** //
add_theme_support('html5', array('search-form'));


// ******************* Add Custom Menus ****************** //

add_theme_support( 'menus' );

// ******************* Add Custom Excerpt Lengths ****************** //

function wpe_excerptlength_index($length) {
    return 160;
}
function wpe_excerptmore($more) {
    return '...<a href="'. get_permalink().'">Read More ></a>';
}

function wpe_excerpt($length_callback='', $more_callback='') {
    global $post;
    if(function_exists($length_callback)){
        add_filter('excerpt_length', $length_callback);
    }
    if(function_exists($more_callback)){
        add_filter('excerpt_more', $more_callback);
    }
    $output = get_the_excerpt();
    $output = apply_filters('wptexturize', $output);
    $output = apply_filters('convert_chars', $output);
    $output = '<p>'.$output.'</p>';
    echo $output;
}

// ******************* Add Post Thumbnails ****************** //

add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 50, 50, true );
add_image_size( 'full-width-ratio', 100, 9999 );

// ******************* Add Custom Post Types & Taxonomies ****************** //

register_post_type('custom', array(
 'label' => __('Custom Post Type'),
 'singular_label' => __('Custom Post Type'),
 'public' => true,
 'show_ui' => true,
 'capability_type' => 'post',
 'hierarchical' => false,
 'rewrite' => true,
 'query_var' => false,
 'has_archive' => true,
 'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'author')
));

add_action( 'init', 'build_taxonomies', 0 );

function build_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy( 'taxo', 'custom', array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Custom Taxonomy', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true ) ); 
}


// ******************* Add Options to Theme Customizer ****************** //

function themename_customize_register($wp_customize){
    
    $wp_customize->add_section('themename_color_scheme', array(
        'title'    => __('Color Scheme', 'themename'),
        'priority' => 120,
    ));

    //  =============================
    //  = Text Input                =
    //  =============================
    $wp_customize->add_setting('themename_theme_options[text_test]', array(
        'default'        => 'Arse!',
        'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
        'type'           => 'option',

    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control('themename_text_test', array(
        'label'      => __('Text Test', 'themename'),
        'section'    => 'themename_color_scheme',
        'settings'   => 'themename_theme_options[text_test]',
    ));

}

add_action('customize_register', 'themename_customize_register');


// ******************* Add Shortcode ****************** //

function secondaryCallout($atts, $content = null) {
 extract(shortcode_atts(array(
 'link' => '#',
    'link_title' => '',
    'content' => '',
    ), $atts));

 $out = '
  <div class="secondaryCallout tertiaryColorBkg">
   '.$content.' <a class="secondaryColorText" title="'.$link_title.'" href="'.$link.'">'.$link_title.' &gt;</a>
  </div>
 ';

    return $out;
}
 
add_shortcode('secondary_callout', 'secondaryCallout');

add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');


// ******************* Include styles Properly ****************** //

add_action('init','theme_enqueue_styles');

function theme_enqueue_styles() {
 wp_enqueue_style( 'them_main', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/boilerplate.css' );
 wp_enqueue_style( 'them_extra1', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/normalize.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'them_extra2', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/animate.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'them_extra3', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/component.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'them_extra4', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/home.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'them_extra5', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/landing_page.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'them_extra5', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/owl.carousel.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'them_extra5', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/owl.transitions.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'them_extra5', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrapTheme.css' );
} 

// ******************* Include jQuery Properly ****************** //
function my_init() {
   
    
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js", false, '2.0.3', true);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
   
    //load a JS file from by theme: js/theme.js
     wp_enqueue_script('my_script2', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/modernizr.custom.js', array('jquery'), '1.0',true);
     wp_enqueue_script('my_script2', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0',true);
     wp_enqueue_script('my_script2', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/imagesloaded.js', array('jquery'), '1.0',true);
     wp_enqueue_script('my_script2', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/skrollr.js', array('jquery'), '1.0',true);
     wp_enqueue_script('my_script2', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/owl.carousel.js', array('jquery'), '1.0',true);
     wp_enqueue_script('my_script2', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/owl.carousel.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0',true);
}
        
}
add_action('init','my_init');
?>
```

Comment: you didn't close the document.ready function in the stack snippet. Add `});` right before `</script>`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I see it right there.     items : 4,
      itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
      itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]
 
  });
</script>

Comment: Actually, in the top JS section, remove the script tags. In the bottom html section, delete the script tags and everything between. You currently have the JS code twice.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is you need to specify "item" as 1 to work in response,

Here is the working code

```
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
      autoPlay: 3000,
      items : 1, // THIS IS IMPORTANT
      responsive : {
            480 : { items : 1  }, // from zero to 480 screen width 4 items
            768 : { items : 2  }, // from 480 screen widthto 768 6 items
            1024 : { items : 3   // from 768 screen width to 1024 8 items
            }
        },
  });
```

Comment: This isn't true any more, at least as far as OwlCarousel2 is concerned. At https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/responsive.html, there is no mention of the "items" property. Furthermore, the responsive object starts at 0 now, not at 480 (or whatever the first breakpoint is).

Answer (score 8):

Okay, I've fixed the snippet.

Things I fixed:

- Added jquery script
- Added owlcarousel script and css **after** jquery
- Closed JS brackets properly.

Suggestion:

Use the browser's console. f12 should open it and then it's easy to find the error.

Your code will rarely "just work", you need to know how to debug it (which is really easy in web development)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

    autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds

    items: 4,
    itemsDesktop: [1199, 3],
    itemsDesktopSmall: [979, 3]

  });
}); // Notice there need to be two sets of closing brackets! One for the .ready and one for the carousel.
```

```css
.grayscale {
  border: 0px solid black;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  /* For Webkit browsers */
  filter: gray;
  /* For IE 6 - 9 */
  -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
  /* Transition for Webkit browsers */
}
.grayscale:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  filter: none;
}
#owl-demo .owl-item {
  margin: 3px;
}
#owl-demo .owl-item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.2/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.2/owl.carousel.js"></script>

<div id="owl-demo">


  <div class="owl-item grayscale" style="width: 293px;">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/technics/" alt="Owl Image">
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item grayscale" style="width: 293px;">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/technics/" alt="Owl Image">
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item grayscale" style="width: 293px;">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/technics/" alt="Owl Image">
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item grayscale" style="width: 293px;">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/technics/" alt="Owl Image">
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item grayscale" style="width: 293px;">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/technics/" alt="Owl Image">
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item grayscale" style="width: 293px;">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/technics/" alt="Owl Image">
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item grayscale" style="width: 293px;">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/technics/" alt="Owl Image">
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item grayscale" style="width: 293px;">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/technics/" alt="Owl Image">
  </div>

</div>

<script>
</script>
```

If you want to use a local copy of jquery, then replace

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="/pathtolocalcopy/jquery.min.js""></script>
```

Comment: my javascript and css is being pulled with a functions.php file. I've been told that is the proper way to do it to keep less errors from happing. I edited my original question and added it above. I'm guessing this is where I need to fix the script?

Comment: @Tyrii The proper way to pull JS and CSS is: `<script src="/relativepathtoyourscripts/myjs.js"></script>`. I don't understand what this has to do with the question or answer though.

Comment: @Tyrii The first problem you need to fix is that you are trying to use jquery without loading it. You can load it two ways: from a local copy on your machine or through a cdn. My answer shows the cdn method, I'll add the other way as well.

Comment: i'll pull using the cdn. :)

Comment: Your way works so i'm not going to complain. Thank you ever so much Slicedtoad.

Answer (score 3):

in addition if you are planning to do restricting the items number as per responsive screen sizes you can use

```
        responsive : {
            480 : { items : 4  }, // from zero to 480 screen width 4 items
            768 : { items : 6  }, // from 480 screen widthto 768 6 items
            1024 : { items : 8   // from 768 screen width to 1024 8 items
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

When You are using jquery 3 then change in your owl carousel js

Fixed by change "andSelf" to "addBack" inside Owlcarousel code.