# Owl-carousel is not working after build the project using vite

Tags: javascript, jquery, tailwind-css, owl-carousel, vite

I use vite to build [this project](https://github.com/AsmaaMK/Manage).
when I use owl-carousel from node_modules it works in development mode but after build, the carousel stops working and gets this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fn')
    at index.781bd673.js:4:36786
    at index.781bd673.js:4:37392
```

so I used it from CDN.

```
<script type="module">
  // CDN --> working after build 
  // import 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js';
  // import 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js';

  // node_modules --> not working after build
  import './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js';
  import './node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js';

  // customize owl carousel
  import './src/js/owl-carousel.js';
</script>
```

How to use it from node_modules without that error??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28070885/owl-carousel-not-working-maybe-i-linked-something-incorrectly

Comment: @MuhammadMahfuzurRahman It's not my problem here. It's working in dev mode but stops after the build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

export jQuery globally

```
// jquery.js file 

import $ from 'jquery'; // from node_modules
window.jQuery = $;
export default $;
```

and import it in owl-carousel.js

```
// owl-carousel.js file

import $ from './jquery.js';
import 'owl.carousel'; // from node_modules

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    margin: 20,
    autoplay: true,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1,
      },
      600: {
        items: 2,
      },
      1000: {
        items: 3,
      },
    },
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The below answer from @Asmaa Mahmoud did not work for me. Below is my solution. I hope this will help someone else struggling with the same issue.

vite.config.js file:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import inject from '@rollup/plugin-inject';
import htmlPurge from 'vite-plugin-purgecss';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    inject({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    }),
    htmlPurge(),
  ],
  css: {
    devSourcemap: true,
  },
});
```

app.js file:

```
import './app.scss';
import 'owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'lazysizes';
import 'owl.carousel';

$(function(){
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({});
});
```